# Why isn't this glsl program working?

Tags: opengl, c++, architecture, glsl

Why isn't this glsl program working ?

```
#shader vertex
#version 430

layout (location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 normal;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 texture_coordinate;
layout (location = 3) in vec4 color;

uniform mat4 phantom_projection_matrix;
uniform mat4 phantom_view_matrix;
uniform mat4 phantom_model_matrix;

out OUT_DATA
{
    vec4 position;
    vec3 normal;
    vec2 texture_coordinate;
    vec4 color; 
} vertex_out;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = phantom_projection_matrix * phantom_view_matrix * phantom_model_matrix * position;

    vertex_out.position             = position;
    vertex_out.normal               = normal;
    vertex_out.texture_coordinate   = texture_coordinate;
    vertex_out.color                = color;    
};

#shader geometry
#version 430

layout (points) in;
layout (points, max_vertices = 1) out;

in IN_DATA
{
    vec4 position;
    vec3 normal;
    vec2 texture_coordinate;
    vec4 color; 
} geometry_in[];

out OUT_DATA
{
    vec4 position;
    vec3 normal;
    vec2 texture_coordinate;
    vec4 color;
} geometry_out;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = gl_in[i].gl_Position;
    EmitVertex();
    EndPrimitive();

    geometry_out.position               = geometry_in[0].position;
    geometry_out.normal                 = geometry_in[0].normal;
    geometry_out.texture_coordinate     = geometry_in[0].texture_coordinate;
    geometry_out.color                  = geometry_in[0].color;
}

#shader fragment
#version 430

layout (location = 0) out vec4 color;

in IN_DATA
{
    vec4 position;
    vec3 normal;
    vec2 texture_coordinate;
    vec4 color; 
} geometry_in;

void main()
{
    color = vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}

#shader tesselation_control
#shader tesselation_evaluation
```

Comment: What's the expected and actual result?

Answer (score 1):

```
gl_Position = gl_in[i].glPosition;
```

The variable i is not specified anywhere, as you're using points as input it has to be of value 0 or you can just use 0 instead (as the Input array is of size 1).